# How can Telegram Bot reply a specific commandusing Bot API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telegram-webhook

I am trying to find a way to make my Telegram bots reply "Hello, please enter your phone number" whenever someone starts the bot using the default "/start" command. Is there a way to do this with Telegram Bot token and Telegram Bot API? Or is there a way for me to do this using BotFather?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fetch the updates your bot gets. You can do this either by calling the [`getUpdates`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) method constantly, or setting up [Webhooks](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook). For more on getting updates, head to [Getting updates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates).

Comment: Hmm thanks for the reply. I understand that getting the chat updates will let me see the reply. But is there no way for me to set automatically how a bot responds to a start message?

Comment: There is no other way. You should listen to the updates somehow :)